# Is it ethical to refer to Russian programmers?

Tags: discussion, ethics

In a question about testing strategies, I wanted to refer to [an article](https://www.yegor256.com/2017/03/24/tdd-that-works.html) by [Yegor Bugayenko](https://www.yegor256.com/about-me.html) which is controversial, but interesting in my opinion. He is a Russian living in Russia. I did not find political statements from him on the Internet after short research.

My questions:

- Should I avoid mentioning his article because of the war in Ukraine?
- Should I mention it because I did not find political statements from him on the web?
- Is this unimportant and a programming article should be seen independently from the person that wrote it?

I'm unsure and would highly appreciate your opinions on this.

Comment: Related: https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/195781/is-it-safe-to-publish-research-papers-in-cooperation-with-russian-academics/195838#195838

Comment: If the war ends in a month, will you be going over all your posts to retroactively add references?

Comment: It used to be that anything resembling [group punishment](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Collective_punishment) was considered immoral and unacceptable. Now you're asking if it's ethical to *not* engage in group punishment.

Comment: Any question about testing strategies is likely to be too broad.  You should consider that first over and above any other factor.  Hint: don't answer questions asking for opinions.

Comment: I would be careful when linking to his articles, not because he is a Russian (discriminating because of that would be wrong), but because he is more than just controversial and often just plain wrong. Some of his OOP approaches are bad on so many levels that I don't know where to start. I haven't read about his testing strategies, though.

Comment: Last time I checked, "He is a _Ukrainian_ living in Russia" :)

Answer (score 22):

There's no site policy against it, and as long as you don't turn it into a political event when using it as a source (such as asking a question like this) I doubt anyone would even think twice about it. It's just not an important detail.

Answer (score 19):

We do not allow political discussions or allow politics to impact content on Stack Overflow. You can refer to whoever's articles you want and you should not mention their country or political affiliation.

Besides, your point is illogical. Why would a war fought somewhere in the world affect *your* choice of references? I can only understand your hesitation if the article itself mentioned some propaganda or was created explicitly for the purpose of fighting the war.

Answer (score 18):

Stack Overflow's guidance is to judge content based on the content, not the author. This argument just as well applies to offsite content. Besides, judging a person just because they happen to live in Russia is wrong, they have no control over what their government is doing. Stack Exchange has an [official stance](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/376743/1377755) regarding users in Russia, and much of what is said there also applies to offsite authors.